# showing commits not yet cherry-picked from a range of commits

Tags: git, git-log

I have two diverged branches `J` and `Z` with an arbitrary number of commits:

```
         .-- a -- b -- ... -- i -- J
        /
... -- o -- x -- b' -- ... -- y -- Z
```

1. Is it possible to show, in `git log`, what commits are in the range 
   of `b..i` that aren't already cherry-picked into `Z`?
2. And, what commits are in the range of `b..i` weren't cherry-picked
   into the range of `b'..y`?

I'm looking for something like `git log Z...i --cherry-pick --right-only --no-merges` but accepts filtering out ranges.

**Edit:**  I wasn't clear on this, but I'm looking for a way to do this in `git log` so that I can see them in context by further using options like `--cherry-mark` and `--left-right`.

Ideally, a way to write something like `git log b..i b'..y --left-right` and having `b..i` treated as *left*..  (As this seems to be the prerequisite.)

Comment: So you want to compare two ranges of commits to figure out whether some of the commits appear only in one of the ranges and not the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `^` to remove commits:

1) `git log Z...i --cherry-pick --right-only --no-merges ^a`

2) `git log y...i --cherry-pick --right-only --no-merges ^a ^x`

Answer (score 2):

`git cherry` is the command you want to use. Take a look at its man page `man git cherry`. It shows exactly your use case:

```
           __*__*__*__*__> <upstream>
          /
fork-point
          \__*__*__<limit>__-__+__> <head>
```